# Exception with " Could not initialize class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument" in COMSOL

Tags: java, comsol

I use COMSOL to read and write excel as shown below:

```
CsBinaryReader inputStream = openBinaryFileStreamReader(excelFilePath);
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

It throws an exception with "Could not initialize class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument". It also shows that "Class: org.openxml3formats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemDocument$Factory" in external Java library.
Would someone help me with this problems. Many thanks[image]